# IE8 and javascript object property, text

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

Using `.text` object property in JavaScript can produce unexpected results in IE8 (blank string or undefined even when it contains a value).

You can use `.innerHTML` object property as a workaround. IE8 seems to like this.

Or, for reliable cross-browser compatability you can use jquery instead to access an object's text property and I could have do so with: `$(this).text()`  See the answer for a good jQuery solution.

**Original Question:** Is, 'text' a reserved javascript word in IE8? I am curious because I could not find any resource that states this.

**JavaScript (`optionObj.innerHTML`) Solution: **

```
// Look for a match in the section dropdown and select it.
$.each($('#' + mySelect + ' option'), function(key, optionObj) {

    // Switched 'optionObj.text' to 'optionObj.innerHTML' for cross-browser compatibility
    if (optionObj.innerHTML == strTextToMatch) {
        // Found a match
        $('#' + mySelect).val(optionObj.text);
        $('#' + mySelect).trigger('change');
    }
});
```

In IE8, `optionObj.text` would sometimes return a blank string, even when I could see in my debugger that it contained a value (I could see by expanding the `optionObj` object)! What was strange is that 10% of the time, `optionObj.text` would return the actual value other than a blank string. That being said, `optionObj.innerHTML` seems to work reliably.

Comment: I'm hardly one to defend the behavior of Internet Explorer(s), but the script interpreter does work properly.

Comment: Since you're using jQuery, is there a reason you're not using [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text) or [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html)? Just curious! :)

Comment: I want to think so, too but wouldn't the interpretor be to blame for problems like this? http://www.tgerm.com/2009/01/javascript-ie-anchortext-property.html

Comment: @Rob - Good catch. Now that you mention it, I would rather use jquery wherever i can!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, text is neither a reserved word, nor a future reserved word, in JScript.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0779sbks(v=vs.85).aspx

---

***Edit*** OH, I see it now.

You're using the wrong `each` function — [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each) instead of `.each()`.
You're also using `.text` instead of [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text). Fixes:

```
var $mySelect = $('#' + mySelect);
$mySelect.find('option').each(function()
{
    var $option = $(this),
        text = $option.text();
    if (text == strTextToMatch) {
        // Found a match
        $mySelect.val(text);
        $mySelect.trigger('change');
    }
});
```

*but guess what: that's is totally unnecessary.* This will suffice:

```
var $mySelect = $('#' + mySelect),
    newVal = $mySelect.find('option:contains(' + strTextToMatch + ')').val();
$mySelect.val(newVal).change();
```

Comment: Assuming there is a difference between browser interpretations of JavaScript, this list of jscript reserved words must be the official microsoft version that applies to IE8+? I wonder what the problem with 'text' was? Maybe my problem was just a fluke.

Comment: I upped this answer's rank b/c it technically did answer my original question, but I have since rephrased it

Comment: Booyea! Thanks for the refactor.